# How can i fix the url of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, redirect

I have just installed the SEBIAN theme, and i set up the magento secure base url and unsecure base url with my domain url like "http://diran.co/" but when i want to click on home menu and logo it is redirecting or displaying "http://diran.co/fashion". I dont want it to be !

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems site base URL is incorrect:

Go to phpmyadmin:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

You will see tow rows. Now update the value as : http://diran.co/

After that clear caches & Session.

**Nice site by the way.**

Comment: Thanks, but the site base url is correct ! I just solved the issue that, there are multi store configuration and need to change the secure and unsecure url on configuration >> web >> ! Thank You once again !

Comment: Welcome....! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be from several areas. 
First thing to do is reindex you URLs.
Second would be cache magento.
Third would be check any static blocks or CMS pages to makes sure they are properly setup.
Clear all fpc, redis, and/or rebuild complition if that is being utilized.

If you theme uses any other configurations from the backend you might want to also check there to make sure there isn't anything that might have been missed.

If you are still having trouble with any of the above then you could try.
http://optimiseblog.co.uk/magento-delete-all-url-rewrite-management-urls-in-the-database/

- Happy Trails -